# Sliced list with false data

Tags: python, list, slice

I am a python beginner and I have a problem. I try to get the first 10.000 items from a list but it returns me wrong data. i noticed that because i first tried to get the first 10/20/50 items(i print the results in a .txt) and i got nothing. Here is some of the code.

```
/*for key in docs:
T_buffer=docs[key]['tf'].items()
keyset.append(T_buffer)
*/
keyseta = list(itertools.chain(*keyset))
keyseta.sort(key=lambda z: z[1], reverse=True)

keyset=keyseta[:8000]

/*
#t0=time.time() #timer ON

#for infile in docs: #upologismos idf kai tf_idf
#    for word in docs[infile]['tf']:
#        docs[infile]['idf'][word]= idf(word,voc)
#        docs[infile]['tf_idf'][word]= docs[infile]['idf'][word] * docs[infile]['tf'][word]

#print time.time()-t0, "seconds"
*/    
loglista1 = open("log1.txt",'w')
print >>loglista1, keyset
```

List contains data such as:

```
 [('uwm', 0.034482758620689655),
 ('s', 0.034482758620689655),
 ('the', 0.034482758620689655),
 ('have', 0.034482758620689655)...]
```

Comment: Where's `loglista1.close()`?

Comment: dangg.... thnx !!!I forgot to close the file.

Comment: It's better to use the [`with`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) statement and [`file.write`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.write) to write content to a file. `print >>` won't work in py3.x.

Comment: If you need to inspect file data as it is written, you can also flush the buffers by calling `loglista1.flush()`.

Comment: list data structure will not maintain the order. You may read the text file in but list will not guarantee it remains the same order. Can you add first few lines of the text file or structure that text file to the question so I can write a concrete solution.

Comment: @find-missing-semicolon List is an ordered collection of items, you're confusing lists with sets.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary good catch yes yes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you're trying to get the first 10, 20, 50 items from a list. If this is the case-

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
for i in range(0,10):
   print list[i] #first 10 items
for i in range(0,20):
   print list[i] #first 20 items
```

Apply the same logic to your list.